# Google error 403 forbidden error

Tags: php

i am using this code to know how to get google images from my site..actually the problem is i am not getting google images to array from my server. i am getting an empty array.
i was run this code in my localhost. it is working fine. but not in my server. getting 403forbidden error. in this page downloadimagesfromgoogle.inc.php at getImageUrls() i checked like this. below is the 
DownloadImagesFromGoogle.inc.php

```
 <?php
    /**
     * To download images of mentioned celebrity/person from google images
     * Strictly for educational/learning purpose only.
     * Please do not use it for commercial purpose as it is illigal !!
     *
     * @author Rochak Chauhan
     * @version 2.0
     * @see No need of cURL
     */
     class DownloadImagesFromGoogle {
     private $sizeLimit=200;
     private $imagesOf="Lindsay";
     private $numberOfImages; 
     private $googleUrlArray=array();

     /**
      * Function to download images from images.google
      *
      * @param string $imagesOf
      * @param int $numberOfImages [OPTIONAL]
      * @param int $sizeLimit [OPTIONAL]
      */
     public function __construct($imagesOf, $numberOfImages=40, $sizeLimit=0) {
      $this->imagesOf=$imagesOf;
      $this->numberOfImages=$numberOfImages;
      $this->sizeLimit=$sizeLimit;    
      $this->googleUrlArray=$this->createGoogleUrl();  
     }

     /**
      * Function the create a list of google image urls
      * 
      * @access private
      * @return array
      */
     private function createGoogleUrl() {
      $imagesOf = $this->imagesOf;
      $numberOfImages = $this->numberOfImages+20;
      $numberOfPages = ($numberOfImages/20)+1;
      $j=0;
      for($i=0; $i<$numberOfPages; $i++ ) {
       $returnArray[] = "http://images.google.co.in/images?q=".rawurlencode($imagesOf)."&hl=en&lr=&start=".$j."&sa=N&gbv=1";   
       $j += 20;
      }
      return $returnArray;
     }

     /**
      * Function to download images from google
      * 
      * @access public
      * @return void
      */
     public function downloadImages() {  
      $imgUrlArray=$this->getImageUrls($urlArray);  
      $today = date("Ymd H:i:s"); 
     $today= strtotime($today);  
      $dir=$today;
      @mkdir($dir,0755);
      @chmod($dir,0755);
      $_SESSION[directory]=$dir;
      //$insert=mysql_query("insert into googlefolders(foldername) values('$_SESSION[directory]')");
      for($i=0; $i<count($imgUrlArray); $i++) {
       $imageName = basename($imgUrlArray[$i]);
       $info = @getimagesize($imgUrlArray[$i]);
       if(trim($this->sizeLimit) != "" && $this->sizeLimit > 0) {
        if (count($info) > 0 && $info[0] >= $this->sizeLimit) {
         if(trim($imageName) != '' ) {
          copy($imgUrlArray[$i], $dir."/".$imageName);
         }
        }
       }
       else {
        if(trim($imageName) != '' ) {
         copy($imgUrlArray[$i], $dir."/".$imageName);
        }
       }
      }
     }

     /**
      * Function to return paths of all images to be downloaded
      *
      * @access public
      * @return array
      */
     public function getImageUrls() {
      $urlArray=$this->googleUrlArray;
      $returnArray=array();
      $returnArray1=array();
      $return=array();

      for ($j=0;$j<count($urlArray);$j++){
       $url=trim($urlArray[$j]);
       $str=$this->getHtmlCode($url);
       echo $str;
       $pattern='/<img src=(.*)\<\/a>/Us';
       preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $returnArray, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
       $returnArray1=$returnArray[1];
       $count=count($returnArray1);
       for ($i=1;$i<$count;$i++) {
        $str1=trim(strip_tags($returnArray[1][$i]));
        $pos1=strrpos($str1,"http://");
        $pos2=strpos($str1," width");
        $link=trim(substr($str1,$pos1,$pos2-$pos1));
        $return[]=$link;

       }
      }
      return $return;
     }

     /**
      * Function to get source code of a url
      *
      * @param string $url
      * @access private
      * @return string
      */
     private function getHtmlCode($url){
      $returnStr="";
      $fp=fopen($url, "r");
      while (!feof($fp)) {
       $returnStr.=fgetc($fp);
      }
      fclose($fp);
      return $returnStr;
     }
    }
```

test.php

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("allow_url_fopen",1);

require_once('DownloadImagesFromGoogle.inc.php');
$downloadImagesFromGoogle = new DownloadImagesFromGoogle("rings", 40, 350);
$downloadImagesFromGoogle->downloadImages();
?>
```

Comment: any body please suggest me how to solve this error

Comment: please anybody give reply. i am trying to do very much, but i have not found any solution

Answer (score 0):

(403)Forbidden is SSL related error. You may look php authentication and authorization topic. Make sure if the image urls is not https otherwise it require ssl client acceptance.